# Laravel 5.2 daily logging unable to write/open the logs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have logging enabled in controllers and also in Scheduler and in artisan commands
and Log is set to daily in config.

Now, if the log has been created via controller then other artisan or schedular cannot access to it and vice versa.
I need a proper implementation and solution in laravel 5.2

My webserver is nginx and os is Ubuntu 14.03

Comment: i have tried adding below code in bootstrap/app.php/
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $filename = storage_path('/logs/laravel-'.php_sapi_name().'.log');
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
but still same issues it does creats log files but artisan commands are not working

Comment: What's the permissions on the logs folder?

Comment: its 777 drwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission error.

The user that artisan creates the log file with is probably your own user. Scheduler may be any user - depends who ran the command; also likely your own user.

The webserver is a user on it's own - different than the account you log in with; with Ubuntu it's www-data.

You have three choices:

After the file is created, modify it's permissions:

1. `chmod o+r logfilename`

   or
2. `chgrp www-data logfilename`

Or, make sure that any file created in that folder is also accessible by anyone:

3. `chgrp www-data foldername`,
   `chmod o+s foldername`

Comment: will try that as soon as possible